Midnight Commander - All files showing as executable when connected via FTP
I am looking to sort out my files and have decided to give Midnight Commander a try.
I need to move/copy/compare files between my local and remote file system so it's pretty convenient that MC colour codes different types of files (pdf, jpg, etc.)
When I established an FTP connection to the remote file system all the files stored there were categorized as executable (with an * in front).
This also colour codes all files the same which makes navigating the file system more difficult.
Is there a way to have the colour codes applied according to file extensions when connected via FTP? Or is this just something that comes with establishing an FTP connection that all files show up as executable and are colour coded as such?
UPDATE: It seems this is not an issue of Midnight Commander nor FTP. The files shown as executable were moved to the server using SMB and in that process (for some reason) the executable flag was set on all files. If I move the files using FTP no new permissions are appended.

See at: https://midnight-commander.org/wiki/doc

I looked through it. Can't find an answer in the FAQ section and the documentation's VFS section (where I would expect to find an answer) seems to be completely empty. If the answer is there in the documentation I can't seem to find it. Could you be more specific on where it is?

If you not need for colors, you may run Midnight Commander with -b or --nocolor option. To redefine the colors of interface elements Midnight Commander:    in section [Colors] in ~/.mc/ini configuration file;   in section describing the terminal in ~/.mc/ini configuration file.You can define your color scheme for each type of terminal;  in environment variable MC_COLOR_TABLE;    through the command-line -C option (or --colors option). mc --help-color

I have colours defined. My problem is, that when using an FTP connection ALL files get classified as an executable and are shown in the same colour (green in my case). because all executable files get the same colour. When I browse the file system on my local machine colour coding works perfectly and all filetypes (pdf, txt, xls, etc.) get a different colour.

Looks like the problem isn't MC nor FTP. See update to original post.
